# Convert string containing scientific notation number to int or float

Tags: python, pandas

The dataframe I am working on has a column containing strings with values like this:

```
df['Records Lost'][0] 
'1,37e+09'
```

This is a string:

```
type(df['Records Lost'][0])
str
```

I tried converting to float but get this error:

```
float(df['Records Lost'][0])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-88765fb941e9> in <module>()
----> 1 float(df['Records Lost'][0])

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,37e+09'
```

Tried `pd.to_numeric` as per @Jezreal

```
pd.to_numeric(df['Records Lost'][0])
ValueError: Unable to parse string "1,37e+09" at position 0

pd.to_numeric([x.replace(',','.') for x in df['Records Lost'][0]])
ValueError: Unable to parse string "." at position 1
```

How do I convert this string to a float/int?

Comment: Change the comma to a period perhaps?

Comment: Sorry, answer was modified.